# App-engine instance hours seem way too high

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I have a small app hosted on GAE with 2 modules. The default module, frontend is
alotted 28 instance hours. The backend is using `basic_scaling:` so only has 8
instance hours available.

I noticed that my application has only been running for 2 hours, yet the backend
module has already used up 76% of its quota! This doesn't make sense to me.
According to the docs, instance hours are calculated by instance uptime (taking
into account multiple instances).

The instance hours should correlate 1:1 with my module's uptime. I have
`max_instances: 1` set. I also checked the running instances just to make sure
that App Engine wasn't spawning multiple instances. It wasn't. I get one
instance, but it's burning up hours faster than it should.

Am I just misinterpreting the docs? If that's the case, how do I lower the rate
it burns through the quota?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be addressed to Google Support.

Comment: According to Google, these Serverfault tags are sponsored tags and it's part of their support package for Bronze (free) tier users. Isn't it better to have the answer out in the open? Stackexchange sites are so much more readable than Google groups.

Comment: They may point users here, but honestly, I've never once seen a Google employee post a single answer here in response to a support query. Additionally, questions like: "why was I billed X?" Can only be answered in an authoritative manner by the company that is doing the billing. Server Fault should never be your first point of call for support - if vendor support is available, we expect that you've contacted them first. When you get an answer from them, by all means come back and answer your own question with the information provided by support.

Comment: [Browsing the Google tags](http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/google-app-engine) does bring up a couple of Google employees in answers.  I'm surprised, because I had the impression of tumbleweeds.

Comment: @KatherineVillyard Did you look at the profiles of everybody answering those questions? Or do you have a shortcut to recognize answers written by Google employees?

Comment: @kasperd I looked at their profiles.  :)  Basically, I clicked through answered questions and looked at the profiles of the people answering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Basic scaling" [means](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#Python_Instance_scaling_and_class) that an instance is created when a request arrives; billing ends "fifteen minutes after a basic instance has finished processing its last request".

The "instance-hours" shown on the bill, dashboards, etc, refer to the B1 instance class, the smallest one; other instance classes are scaled proportionately. For example, if an instance of class B2 (the default) spends 5 minutes starting up and processing a request, then goes idle, those 20 minutes of B2 will show up as 40 minutes (0.66 "instance hours").

Thus, there is nothing impossible in 2 hours of elapsed (wall-clock) time of a basic-scaling module consuming 6 "instance hours" on a single instance -- all it takes is for that instance to have a sufficiently high instance class.

There are no instance classes counting as 3 times a B1; but for example instance class B4 counts as 4 times a B1, so it would consume 6 instance hours in 1.5 hours of elapsed-time activity, counting the 15 minutes after it goes idle each time.

6 requests in 2 hours, equally spaced, each processed "instantly" (thus counting only the 15 minutes after it goes idle) by a B4 instance, for example, would show up as "6 instance hours" (6 * 0.25 * 4), i.e, 75% of the 8-hours "free quota" for backend "instance hours".

If you show the `.yaml` file configuring the module, and the pattern of activity (which you can evince from the timestamps in the logs), it is possible to check these hypotheses. Without such extra information, hypotheses are all we can propose!-)